# Standard UTC offset (Without DST) for a give TimeZone in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone-offset, pytz

I have a requirement where i need to group several timezone codes based on standrad UTC offset (Without DST), for example - all the time zone with standard UTC offset value between 4 and 6 will be part of one group and so one.

How can i get the standard UTC offset for a timezone using timezone code?

I tried below method but it gives me the offset with DST.

```
pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem').localize(datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)).strftime('%z')
```

Comment: What's the "standard UTC offset"? You're aware that timezones have different offsets during different times of the year? Does your use case mean you can get an offset for one specific point in time? Or you want… without DST always?

Comment: The `standard UTC offset` is the one specified for that specific date. Some countries always use summer time, some always use winter time, some switch and some use half-hours simply to have a different timezone from their neighbors. And China uses the same offset despite crossing 5 time zones.

Comment: I suspect what you refer to as `standard UTC offset` is the base offset for that specific country/timezone, which is still defined by the country's laws. Only [nautical time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_time) is based solely on longitude

Comment: @Panagiotis If some timezone *always* uses the same offset, then the terms "winter" and "summer time" have no meaning.

Comment: @deceze Second option, i need the offset values without DST.

Comment: @deceze that's my point too. There's no "standard"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the `.dst()` method; it gives you the timedelta of the DST. If subtracted from the `.utcoffset()`, you get the "standard" UTC offset of the time zone.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt_woDST = datetime(2011,1,1, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Asia/Jerusalem'))
# 2011-01-01 00:00:00+02:00 
dt_DST = datetime(2011,6,1, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Asia/Jerusalem'))
# 2011-06-01 00:00:00+03:00

utcoff0 = (dt_woDST.utcoffset()-dt_woDST.dst()).total_seconds()
utcoff1 = (dt_DST.utcoffset()-dt_DST.dst()).total_seconds()

print(utcoff0, utcoff0 == utcoff1)
# 7200.0 True
```

Note: I'm using Python 3.9's `zoneinfo` here; of course this also works with datetime objects that you localized with `pytz` timezone objects.